# How do I map <q-1> to close file opened in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I'm working with a particularly stubborn keyboard where the SHIFT key simply doesn't seem to stay down when I need it to, especially when I'm typing stuff that includes keys that are further towards the top of the keyboard. Typing '~' somehow almost always types '`', and typing special characters almost always leads to the corresponding numbers being typed eg. when I try to type '@' I get '2','4' for '$' and so on

I primarily use vim these days, and was wondering is it's possible to map  to  so that when I want to close a file without writing, I can do it without having to worry about whether I have typed '1' or '!'

Help much appreciated

Comment: Simple solution: buy a new keyboard. Less simple but cheaper solution: cleanup your keyboard.

Comment: Not an option at the very moment unfortunately.... And I'm not really sure if the problem is with the keyboard or my unflexible fingers :(

Comment: Either way, a vim mapping is not a *real* solution: re-education or a new keyboard are *real* solutions. Anyway, try `:nnoremap <F6> :w!<CR>`.

Comment: Use the other shift key? There's usually two of them... And I seem to remember that it's generally taught to use the shift key of the opposite hand that has to type the key you want shifted (although I'd be one of the first to admit I have rather horrible keyboarding practice...).

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to enter colon easily then you can add `cnoremap q1 q!` to your .vimrc so it wouldn't matter if you entered `!` or `1` at the end of a command. If colon is also a difficult to enter character then you can create mapping in the normal mode by adding `noremap q1 :q!<CR>`. Obviously you can create both mappings.

However i'd think of a new keyboard (:

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working... I get "Trailing Characters" for ':q1' using the first method :(

Comment: Could you please explain in details at which moment you receive this message? Did you try the second option?

Comment: @navinpai This advice is not much helpful if one fails to type `q1` fast enough. Likely this is the source of the problem with “Trailing Characters”.

Comment: @navinpai “Fast enough” is controlled by `&timeout` and `&timeoutlen` options.